# Access files outside of webroot through alias and .htaccess rule

Tags: .htaccess

I need to make PDF files that are stored in a folder (with subfolders) outside of the web root publically accessible by a plain URL. An alias has been created in Apache that leads this folder so what I need now is a redirect rule in .htaccess to make this work.

I have this alias: https://www.examplesite.com/certificate

The URLs that will be used to access these PDFs are for example: https://www.examplesite.com/certificate/2018/LGOIGD9E9345034GJERGJER.PDF
https://www.examplesite.com/certificate/2017/GSDFJGLKJNL345L34LSNFLSD.PDF

How should I format my redirect rule in .htaccess to decide if the file is to be downloaded or viewed in the browser?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about the noise, I found the answer by myself:

```
<FilesMatch "\.pdf$">

ForceType applicaton/octet-stream

Header set Content-Disposition attachment

</FilesMatch>
```